# convert parse to image in nsarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uiimage

Can anyone please help me here? scenario is:

1. I have a view controller, page view controller, and a content for page view controller.
2. The app is to initially load 3 pages of images, and on the 3rd page a button will then appear. if pressed it'll be directed to the main menu page.
3. all images are loaded from parse.

I previously had a separate program for page view controller and another for parse image loader, executed perfectly. however when I combine both together it fails. based on what I understand is that, images from parse are stored as `NSData`. however, in my page view controller, i'm using index to load the images. I tried converting `NSData` to `NSArray` using KeyedAchiver however it couldn't work.

I also notice that my image loaded from parse doesn't come in the sequence I want. So, if possible, please help to advise on this!

below are the codes. thanks in advance!

```
//***********************view controller
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <parse/parse.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize parseImageData,pageImages; //UIImage, NSData

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create the data model
 //   _pageTitles = @[@"New York Cheese", @"Vanilla Cake", @"Green Tea Cake", @"Choc Indulgence"];
 //   _pageImages = @[@"pic1.png", @"pic2.png", @"pic3.png", @"pic4.png"];
    _pageTitles = @[@"New York Cheese", @"Vanilla Cake"];


    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

        // Change the size of page view controller
        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

        [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
        [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


        NSLog(@"viewcontroller.m viewdidload complete");

    }

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        NSLog(@"out of range!");
        return nil;
    }



    NSLog(@"viewcontroller.m update index");   


    //add my own parse program

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Pictures"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            NSLog(@"picture queried");
            NSLog(@"array %@",objects);

            NSArray *imageFilesArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:objects];

            PFObject *imageObject = [imageFilesArray objectAtIndex:index];
            PFFile *imageFile = [imageObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
            //            scrolling.hidden = NO;
            //            [scrolling startAnimating];


            NSLog(@"pffile %@",imageFile);

            [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if(!error){
                    //                    scrolling.hidden = YES;
                    //imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    pageImages = data;
                    parseImageData = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    NSLog(@"nsdata translated %@",parseImageData);
                    //               pageContentViewController.imageFile = data;
                }
            }];
        }}];

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    // pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    NSLog(@"self.pagetitles[index]");
    //pageContentViewController.imageFile = parseImageData;

    NSArray *pageImagesArray = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:pageImages];

    pageContentViewController.imageFile = pageImagesArray[index];
    NSLog(@"pagecontentviewcontroller.imagefile is %@",pageContentViewController.imageFile);
    NSLog(@"self.parseImageData %lu",(unsigned long)index);

    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;
        return pageContentViewController;

}

//*****************PAGE CONTENT CONTROLLER PART
#import "PageContentViewController.h"
#import <parse/parse.h>

@interface PageContentViewController ()

@end

@implementation PageContentViewController
@synthesize imageFile,titleText,backgroundImageView; //NSData, NSString, IBOutlet UIImage

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageFile];
    backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageFile];
    self.titleLabel.text = self.titleText;

    NSLog(@"Image supposed be loaded...%@",imageFile);
    NSLog(@"title supposed be loaded...%@",titleText);



}
```

Comment: How is `parseImageData` declared? Also `@synthesize` has been out-dated for several years, remove it and access the property  as `self. parseImageData `, the same goes for `pagetitles`. Without `@synthesize` ivars are automatically generated with a leading underscore, that may help understand some of the commented-out code.

Comment: @zaph, i'm doing self-learning obj-c from appcoda. it's indeed the old tutorials lol. parseImageData is an UIImage, and pageTitles is NSArray.